# Recent Camera gets overrided with the default image

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an image grid, which was designed to have Add more button, when clicked on it. A new image placeholder should appear with a default image, when clicked on it the camera gets invoked and should update the default image with the picture taken. In my case, the camera picture is not getting updated but the default picture stays. When clicked on the add more, instead of the default picture the recent camera picture is getting appeared. I think there is a problem with rendering part of the code.

Here is my code

```
var Summary = React.createClass({
      getInitialState: function(){
        return {
          picTriggers: [],
          number:0,
          image:"https://www.bignerdranch.com/img/blog/2014/07/Button-2.png"
        }
      },


     camera: function(){

        var that = this;
        var image = this.state.image;
          navigator.camera.getPicture(onSuccess, onFail, { quality: 50,
            destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL
          });

          function onSuccess(imageData) {
              console.log(imageData);
              var finalimage = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageData;
              that.setState({image: finalimage});
          }


         function onFail(message) {
            alert('Failed because: ' + message);
         }


     },


    newButton: function(){
      var number = this.state.number;
      number = number+1;
      var picTriggers = this.state.picTriggers;
      picTriggers.push(<img id={"div"+number} src={this.state.image} onClick={this.camera} className="addpicture"/>);
      this.setState({picTriggers: picTriggers, number:number});
    },

    render: function(){

        return(
          <div>
            {this.state.picTriggers}
            <button onClick={this.newButton}>
              {this.state.number>0?"Add More":"Add a picture"}
            </button>
            <button className="uploadselected"> Upload Selected </button>
          </div>);

      }

    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm following this correctly, the flow here looks like:

- First render: `Add a picture` button is rendered
- If that button is clicked, a default image is shown via `#newButton`
- If that image is clicked, the `#camera` function gets an image asynchronously and updates state with the image.
- This will trigger `#render`. But you haven't done anything at this point to add a new item to `picTriggers` with the new image, so the old image displays.
- When you click `Add More`, it runs `#newButton` again and you get your image rendered.

I think you could make your life much easier by just maintaining an array of `imgSrcs` instead of an array of rendered components. When you get the camera image, add to the array:

```
var finalImage = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageData;
// Better not to mutate state directly, so make a new array
// with slice, dropping the default image
var imgSrcs = this.state.imgSrcs.slice(0, -1);
imgSrcs.push(finalImage);
this.setState({ imgSrcs: imgSrcs });
```

And in `#newButton`, you just add the default image to the end of the array:

```
var imgSrcs = this.state.imgSrcs.concat([this.state.defaultImage]);
this.setState({ imgSrcs: imgSrcs });
```

Now you have a simple rendering problem, rendering a list of images, instead of a hard state problem, making sure your pre-rendered components are in sync each time `#render` is called.

Comment: But there seems to be no definitive way of binding the image to the particular div right? I mean when the user clicks the div again every thing seems to fail

Comment: You should be able to use the image url as the `key` property - does that solve the issue? I think once you're rendering a simple list of image URLs you should have a much simpler problem - e.g. you could remove the `onClick` handler if `imgSrc !== defaultImage`.

Comment: Yeah, that solves one issue, but I'll update my exact issue in another post

Comment: Hi, can you take a look at here
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31890489/data-structure-for-storing-images-when-i-convert-the-following-static-grid-int